# Write each of the following propositions as logical expressions involving P, Q and R.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Q:1. Let P, Q and R be propositions defined as follows:
P: I am hungry.
Q: The fridge is empty.
R: It is Saturday.
Write each of the following propositions as logical expressions involving P, Q
and R.
(a) I am hungry and the fridge is not empty.

ANS: Would this be like P is hungry but not Q is empty ??

Comment: "I am hungry is hungry" is meaningless and "but" is not a valid logical connector.

Comment: "I am hungry (P) **and** the fridge is not empty (not-Q)".

Comment: And yes, in propositional logic "A but B" is the same as "A and B"

Comment: Sigh.  This simple  stuff actually needs to be taught and as simple as it is, kids do not understand it?